# Is it safe to store captcha in cookie?

Tags: java, security, web-applications, captcha

I've got a web-app which is using `captcha`. It puts `SecretCode` attribute in cookie and then I should compare two codes from `HTML` form and cookie. But does it safe enough to store `SecretCode` this way? As I know you can not read cookie from anoter domain.

Comment: No, captcha's should be stores somewhere inaccessible to the user. (the server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** not safe, you can simply create bot to read cookies and create input